# Translating "trapline"

Tags: traducción

How to translate [trapline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapline) into Spanish? 
I would like to translate the term that refers to the fur trade in North America, and something like "línea de trampas" sounds rather odd. I'd appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I can only found a few examples. The traslation in those cases is _línea de trampas_. Examples: [Diccionario de ecología](https://books.google.es/books?id=vt1BF53n3woC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=linea+de+trampas+trapline&source=bl&ots=LkGBbcvK8D&sig=x45gfeeEtR1CEOhWyXGAJk7iJOE&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizh-Ka7fPQAhXBiRoKHYA5DRUQ6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=trapline&f=false), [Glosario Ecología](http://glosarios.servidor-alicante.com/ecologia/linea-de-trampas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I am not sure if there is a special term for this practice (I haven't found it), you might want to look into the definition of trapline to get some hints of how to translate it:

> a trapline is a route along which a trapper sets traps for his or her quarry

The key here would be in "*route*", which could give you the following options:

- Ruta de trampas (*trap route*)
- Sendero de trampas (*trap route/road*)
- Camino de trampas (*trap road*)
- Secuencia de trampas (*sequence of traps*)
- Trampas secuenciales (*sequential traps*)
- Trampas en secuencia (*traps in sequence*)

Hopefully that will get you started with a better translation than "*línea de trampas*".

Further research indicates others have translated this as "trampas en línea" (*traps in a line*).